# AudioGraph Memory Increase UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10-universal

I created two AudioGraphs, one for the computer voice and one for the microphone. In both cases, once the graph is started, the memory continues to increase even in the case of the computer voice graph even after the sentence is finished. Even in the microphone graph when the graph starts the memory continues to increase.

This can be seen in the visual studio diagnostic tools.

MainPage.xaml:

```
    <Grid>
        <Button x:Name="BtnMicrophone" Content="Start Graph Microphone" Click="BtnMicrophone_Click" Margin="10,47,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <Button x:Name="BtnComputerVoice" Content="Start Graph Computer" Click="BtnComputerVoice_Click" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="169"/>
    </Grid>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
    MediaSourceAudioInputNode mediaInput;
    AudioFrameOutputNode frameOutputNode;
    AudioDeviceOutputNode deviceOutput;
    MediaSource mediaVoice;
    AudioGraph graph;

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override async void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        await InitializeAudioGraph();
    }

    private async void BtnComputerVoice_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        graph.Stop();
        graph.ResetAllNodes();

        //Start AudioGraph Computer
        var synth = new Windows.Media.SpeechSynthesis.SpeechSynthesizer();

        SpeechSynthesisStream stream = null;

        stream = await synth.SynthesizeTextToStreamAsync("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.");
        synth.Dispose();

        mediaVoice = MediaSource.CreateFromStream(stream, stream.ContentType);

        CreateMediaSourceAudioInputNodeResult fileInputResult = await graph.CreateMediaSourceAudioInputNodeAsync(mediaVoice);
        if (MediaSourceAudioInputNodeCreationStatus.Success != fileInputResult.Status) { return; }

        mediaInput = fileInputResult.Node;
        mediaInput.AddOutgoingConnection(deviceOutput);

        frameOutputNode = graph.CreateFrameOutputNode();
        mediaInput.AddOutgoingConnection(frameOutputNode);
        frameOutputNode.OutgoingGain = 4;
        graph.Start();
    }

    private async void BtnMicrophone_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (graph != null)
        {
            graph.Stop();
            graph.ResetAllNodes();
        }

        if (mediaInput != null)
        {
            mediaInput.Stop();
            mediaInput.Dispose();
            mediaInput = null;
        }
         
        //Start AudioGraph Microphone
        CreateAudioDeviceInputNodeResult fileInputResult = await graph.CreateDeviceInputNodeAsync(Windows.Media.Capture.MediaCategory.Speech);
        if (AudioDeviceNodeCreationStatus.Success != fileInputResult.Status)
        {
            return;
        }
        AudioDeviceInputNode deviceInput = fileInputResult.DeviceInputNode;

        frameOutputNode = graph.CreateFrameOutputNode();
        deviceInput.AddOutgoingConnection(frameOutputNode);
        graph.Start();
    }

    public async Task InitializeAudioGraph()
    {
        // Create an AudioGraph with default settings
        AudioGraphSettings settings = new AudioGraphSettings(AudioRenderCategory.Media);
        CreateAudioGraphResult result = await AudioGraph.CreateAsync(settings);
        if (result.Status != AudioGraphCreationStatus.Success)
        {
            return;
        }
        graph = result.Graph;

        // Create a device output node
        CreateAudioDeviceOutputNodeResult deviceOutputNodeResult = await graph.CreateDeviceOutputNodeAsync();
        if (deviceOutputNodeResult.Status != AudioDeviceNodeCreationStatus.Success)
        {
            return;
        }
        deviceOutput = deviceOutputNodeResult.DeviceOutputNode;
    }
```

How can I solve the problem of constant memory increase that occurs after starting the grap?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The source of the continuous increase in memory comes from `AudioFrameOutputNode`, which is designed to allow developers to customize code to receive and process audio data output from audio graphs.

Judging from the code you currently provide, no audio data processing code is needed, so adding this output node is unnecessary.

You can try to comment the following code, the memory will stop unlimited growth:

```cs
//frameOutputNode = graph.CreateFrameOutputNode();
//mediaInput.AddOutgoingConnection(frameOutputNode);
//frameOutputNode.OutgoingGain = 4;
```

Comment: I need audio data processing for fft

Comment: Hello, if you need `AudioFrameOutputNode`, then you can release the node or the generated `AudioFrame` in time after executing the related processing program.

Comment: Is possible a small example?

Comment: Hello, in the code you currently provide, I did not find the code for how you handle `AudioFrame`. If the FFT you are referring to involves a third-party library, please check the documentation of the relevant library or consult the developer of the library